# Calculate distance between one individual to every predator on same date

Tags: r, gps, distance

I am calculating the distance between moose and wolves using UTM33 coordinates over the period of 2 years (large dataset) in R. I want to have a final table that gives me something like mooseID mooseDate mooseX mooseY wolfID wolfDate wolfX wolfY Distance(m). So far I think I've been able to calculate the distance, but can't seem to match the dates (for example, for every moose position, I want to find the distance of all the wolves at that moment). Also I have more data for the moose (40 individuals) than the wolves (10 individuals) and moose locations are recorded every 2h whereas wolf locations are recorded every 4h. All I'm interested to have right now is to see within a same day the distance of every moose to every wolf and later to filter encounters that are <1000m (I'd like to see all wolves that were close to the moose that day, and not just the closest).

How can I change my code so that dates match? Here is the code I have so far.

```
#Change to data.table and sort date format
mloc = data.table(moosesubset)
wloc = data.table(wolfsubset)
mloc$DateTime=as.POSIXct(mloc$DateTime, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
wloc$DateTime=as.POSIXct(wloc$DateTime, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

#Sort by date
Sortmoose = mloc[order(as.Date(mloc$DateTime,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),]
Sortwolf = wloc[order(as.Date(wloc$DateTime,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),]

# Try distances only
moosewolf=cbind(Sortmoose,Sortwolf)
moosewolf$distance= sqrt(((moosewolf[,12]-moosewolf[,5])^2)+(moosewolf[,13]-moosewolf[,6])^2)

names(moosewolf)=c("Id","MooseID","Moose DateTime","Moose X", "Moose Y","Moose Altitude",
                   "Id", "Wolf ID", "Wolf DateTime", "Wolf X", "Wolf Y", "Wolf Altitude",
                   "Distance(m)")                      
moosewolf$`Distance(m)`= round(moosewolf$`Distance(m)`)
encounters=moosewolf[which(moosewolf$`Distance(m)`<1000)]
```

Sample of sorted moosewolf data:
[Data][1]

**Id    MooseID Moose DateTime  Moose X Moose Y Moose Altitude  Id  Wolf ID Wolf DateTime   Wolf X  Wolf Y  Wolf Altitude   Distance(m)**

1   49584637    E1801   22-02-18 0:00   363062  6757655 251 49589936    M18-12  22-02-18 12:00  355361  6754244 305 8423

2   49585438    E1802   22-02-18 0:00   361651  6738182 410 49589999    M18-12  22-02-18 13:00  355568  6754157 298 17094

3   49579657    E1803   22-02-18 0:00   362825  6755879 258 49589933    M18-12  22-02-18 14:00  355792  6754679 314 7135

4   49586561    E1804   22-02-18 0:00   366561  6749456 437 49589995    M18-12  22-02-18 15:00  355792  6754691 303 11974

5   49590435    E1806   22-02-18 0:00   368068  6756278 304 49589929    M18-12  22-02-18 16:00  354580  6755783 331 13497

6   49584613    E1807   22-02-18 0:00   364385  6759082 244 49589992    M18-12  22-02-18 17:00  354659  6756301 351 10116

7   49582430    E1808   22-02-18 0:00   375119  6764880 551 49589990    M18-12  22-02-18 18:00  354659  6756306 350 22184

8   49582803    E1809   22-02-18 0:00   380085  6757936 427 49589988    M18-12  22-02-18 19:00  354655  6756301 351 25483

9   49584608    E1801   22-02-18 1:00   363058  6757655 248 49589987    M18-12  22-02-18 20:00  354655  6756296 340 8512

10  49584624    E1801   22-02-18 2:00   363055  6757639 278 49589918    M18-12  22-02-18 21:00  354655  6756302 353 8506

11  49584623    E1801   22-02-18 3:00   363119  6757570 315 49589980    M18-12  22-02-18 22:00  354621  6756376 354 8581

12  49584621    E1801   22-02-18 4:00   363164  6757746 303 49589890    M18-12  22-02-18 23:00  354638  6756203 358 8664

13  49584615    E1801   22-02-18 5:00   363152  6757686 247 49589883    M18-12  23-02-18 0:00   354881  6755596 328 8531

14  49584590    E1801   22-02-18 6:00   363152  6757698 252 49586495    M18-13  22-02-18 12:00  355335  6754240 308 8548

15  49584562    E1801   22-02-18 7:00   363133  6757697 219 49586492    M18-13  22-02-18 13:00  355457  6754213 304 8430

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the data, I can add more if needed!

Comment: Edit the question and paste data there so someone can copy it directly.

Comment: I've tried putting the columns but the formatting isn't allowing me to do so, you should be able to copy paste into excel and transfer to R though! If there's another way to do this, please tell me so, I've included the 15 first entries (dates are sorted so first entries of 2018)